# 2 rods connected at a pivot and attached to a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, torque, equilibrium, statics

I have a question concerning this problem
[image]

First I calculate F1 by taking the origin at F2 and imposing equilibrium for the torque thus getting $ F_1 = \frac{a}{a+b} F $ and similarly for F2, then I impose the torque equilibrium for each rod and get the force of the spring $ F_s = \frac{a}{a+b} \frac{F}{\tan{\theta}} $ but then the problem asks to calculate the force on the upper pivot of the rod on the right, and by balancing the torque for each rod using only the force of the other rod and summing them I get a total force on the pivot of F upwards and I'm wondering ( if it's correct) where does this force come from and how can it arise internal of a body. Also the last question asked if the lower part has a certain Young's modulus, to calculate the cross-section of the lower part given the displacement and there I took it that I can use the force of the string and thus the equation $ A = \frac{f_s l}{Y \Delta l}$ where l is just (a+b), is it sensible to do so?